# Nuxt.js - Add two layouts in page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am a beginner in **Nuxt.js** and I am converting a project of Vue to Nuxt.js and I wanted to use two layouts (the default one and another) on one page. The logic is this:
The first layout is the (default) or header which is on all pages and the second layout is the **settings bar**.

In **settings** page i have 3 routes (see project structure here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQzAt.png)):

1. settings/avatar
2. settings/account
3. settings/about

I want the **Settings bar** to be the same for three routes. I can add the Settings bar to all three child pages like: `layout: 'settings-bar'` but then could not set the Header layout. In my Vue project i only used in settings page: Settings bar component and below `<router-view></router-view>` to change the components. Any idea how i can do this? in docs can not find anything. See other screenshots here to better understand:

[image: project]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to have multiple layouts on one page. However what you are describing could be managed with [Child Components](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtchild-component).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I managed to fix it somehow, folders structure: [link](https://i.imgur.com/l9L4BPU.png) & putting `<nuxt-child />` in settings.vue

Comment: This is a matter of ordering. Layouts contain pages, pages contain components. So it doesn't make sense to have multiple layouts in a single page: *there aren't **ever** any layouts in a page*, instead the pages are inside the layout. As answer suggests, check out components.

Comment: It is doable, check my answer for the *how*.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually doable to have nested layouts in Nuxt, meanwhile: it's a bit hacky and hard to read and I'm not sure that I may recommend it at a bigger scale. Tried it, do not recommend but if it's really needed, here is the solution.

`layouts/default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt v-if="!$slots.default" />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

`layouts/newLayout.vue`

```html
<template>
  <default-layout>
    <h1>Surrounding layout</h1>
    <nuxt />
  </default-layout>
</template>

<script>
import DefaultLayout from '~/layouts/default.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DefaultLayout
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, you can use it anywhere with

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'newLayout' // name of your new layout
}
</script>
```

Kudos to this article: https://constantsolutions.dk/2020/02/nested-layouts-in-nuxt-vue-js/

Not sure, but the article itself may be from this github post: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/785#issuecomment-422365721

Comment: This will cause `default-layout` to re-render each time there is a transitions between routes with different "child" layouts. I was wondering if it's possible in Nuxt to have a wrapper layout w/o re-renders, e.g. for global components as notifications list, header with user info etc

Comment: At the end, using a simple component is probably simpler and more clean. Nesting layouts is kinda a hack anyway. @markoffden