# Is it possible to pass layout information from a page to a component in Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have 2 default layouts - one for mobile and one for desktop. I assign them to my pages via the layout property and a user agent middleware.

Now I'd like to pass that layout information to the components used on the page as well (e.g. as a prop) so that I can build variations of the same component for different devices. Is that possible? And if so, is it good practice to do this or is this not the intended layout usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reminder of the structure of a View in Nuxt (layouts are used to wrap pages, hence `layout` can only be used on pages)

[image]

As [shown here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/layout), you can use a function and make a conditional while in your page file

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout({ route }) {
    if (route.name === 'index') {
      return 'index-layout'
    } else {
      return 'some-other-one'
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

As long as this is available in [Nuxt's context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers), you should be able to use it totally fine (usually, Nuxt modules do properly expose those in the context).

---

As if it's a good practice, I'd say no.
Nowadays, we are supposed to write our code from mobile-first to desktop viewports. And make the whole thing adaptative thanks to CSS.

You should **not** use 2 different layouts for `mobile` and `desktop` because it's easier to design. Meanwhile, if for some **good reason**, there is a matter of providing a totally different experience based on their user agent, maybe you could use it in that matter.

But since [Layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#layouts) are used to wrap things, some may argue that you can do that too.
PS: also, if I quote the documentation

> Layouts are a great help when you want to change the look and feel of your Nuxt app. For example you want to include a sidebar or have distinct layouts for mobile and desktop.

My position on this, is that it depends on the exact code you do have in those 2 layouts.
I tend to think that it's totally fine for those use-cases (with quite decent UI differences):

- admin / guest
- sidebar / fullscreen interface

---

At the end, a layout is basically a code separation convention rather than something really unique, because it could also be a page with another page nested in it.
On a side not, if one day you want to nest some layouts, you can achieve it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66904133/8816585).

Comment: Layout use cases: User registration&login flows, dashboards (e.g. end-user vs internal team), e-commerce checkout flow, etc.